# Is there a bug where extra margin appears on addins on outlook.office.com?

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office-ui-fabric

After refreshing outlook.office.com today, I noticed that my addins all have 18px of margin above them in the read and compose views. The margin is on the 'commands-353' class (which is also the 'ms-Panel-commands' element). This element is a sibling of 'ms-Panel-contentInner' and is pushing the addin inner content down causing it to overflow off of the page and adding a scrollbar.

I work on an addin development team and this is affecting our addin. I am wondering if this is a known issue that will be fixed, or if there is a workaround that we should plan to implement for our addin.

[Screenshot of The HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDus4.jpg)

[Screenshot of the margin above the addin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yqx3.png)

Comment: I think you may be having an Office Fabric JS issue with Panel?  "office-ui-fabric" may be a better tag.

Comment: We are able to repro this bug. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available soon.